# Get string between 2 delimiters using C++ STl TR1 regular expressions

Tags: c++, regex, stl

I want to extract string between open and close bracket.So if the content is

145(5)(7)

the output must be

**5**

**7**

I tried with C++ STL TR1  using below code

```
const std::tr1::regex pattern("\\((.*?)\\)");

// the source text
std::string text= "145(5)(7)";

 const std::tr1::sregex_token_iterator end;
 for (std::tr1::sregex_token_iterator i(text.begin(),
      text.end(), pattern);
      i != end;
      ++i)
 {
      std::cout << *i << std::endl;
 }
```

I am getting the output as,

**(5)**

**(7)**

I want the output without delimiters.

Please help me to meet my requirement using STL TR1.

Comment: Considering that TR1 is bordering on ancient, what compiler and standard library are you using? Which versions of them?

Comment: I am using VS2008.

Comment: That is a very old compiler, and it doesn't support much of the upcoming C++11 standard. So even if you have some functionality from TR1 you can't trust that it will be all working perfectly. You should really try to update to a later version of VS.

Comment: You do not need `regex` for this.  you can use `getline` and a `stringstream` and that is compatible with all compilers.

Comment: Try `const std::tr1::sregex_iterator end; for (std::tr1::sregex_iterator i(text.begin(),
       text.end(), pattern);
       i != end;
       ++i)
  {
       std::cout << (*i).str(1) << std::endl;
  }`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - (*i).str() is not taking any argument

Comment: I tested in Visual Studio 2012, and your code works if you replace `sregex_token_iterator` with `sregex_iterator`, and then use `(*i).str(1)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `sregex_iterator` instead of `sregex_token_iterator` and then access the submatches via `.str(n)`:

```
const std::tr1::regex pattern1("\\((.*?)\\)");
std::string text= "145(5)(7)";
const std::tr1::sregex_iterator end;
for (std::tr1::sregex_iterator i(text.begin(),
    text.end(), pattern1);
    i != end;
    ++i)
{
    std::cout << (*i).str(1) << std::endl;
}
```

[image]